# Direct Link to IRC Server with Double ##

Tags: irc

Trying to create a direct link to an IRC channel with double octothorpes (##).

Freenode [policy](http://freenode.net/policy.shtml#offtopic) dictates off-topic channels require ## before the channel name.

This [O'Reilly 'hack' post](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/2018) gives solid instructions for how to link to a channel and open in the default client on a system, but no guidance for channels with doubles.

Links to single channels are formatted as "irc://irc-server:port/channel?key"

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hack to figure this one out, but I managed.

By going to [webchat.freenode.net](https://webchat.freenode.net/) I was able to create a webchat link to the channel successfully. What I noticed was when created, the webchat created link had "?channels=%23%236.00.1x" appended for the channel (the channel I was trying to link to was ##6.00.1x).

Modifying this slightly left me with: "irc://chat.freenode.net/%23%236.00.1x" for the channel.

Doing a bit more research for this post led me to a [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) article about URL Enconding References for ASCII Characters.

Perhaps a newbie question and answer, but a process none the less.